# Fast-travel, while keeping items

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I regularly host a fairly casual ARK group with a couple of friends. We'd like to build multiple bases around the island, but fast-traveling with the beds drops your whole inventory on the ground, which is pretty off-putting.

Is there any way to fast-traveling that does not empty my inventory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, it looks like beds are the only way.

However, at time of posting, and update called [*Tek Tier*](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Tek_Tier) is expected to come out tomorrow (January 30th, 2017).  In that update, will include teleporters.  I can't find out how they function, but if I had to guess, you can probably teleport between two or more teleporters that you create, potentially linking together a giant teleportation network.

You can read more about the update [here](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/arks-biggest-patch-ever-coming-next-week-heres-wha/1100-6447343/).